# How to send close frame from java server to web socket?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, server-side

I'm having hard time figuring out how to send a close frame from java server to a web socket, I got the streams set handshaking is going well and also the data is normally received but to properly close the socket it seems that I've to send some closing frame to the client(web socket), So, how to get it done?

Comment: are you using a JSR-356 implementation?

Comment: @evanchooly No, i'm using low level coding

Comment: @MRefaat you should post some code. also note that [RFC6455: the WebSocket Protocol spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) allows for Half-Close connections (eg: where one side has sent a close, but the other still sends frames until its ready to close)